# How to write this json return from an API to google sheet via google script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm calling an API and get this JSON back:

```
var fact={"columns":["Emerging Markets Sovereing Debt","Emerging Markets Corporate Bonds","US REITs","US Leveraged Loans","AC World Equity","Private Equity","US Long Treasuries","US Large Cap","US Cash","Euro area Large Cap","Emerging Markets Equity","UK Large Cap","Emerging Markets Local Currency Debt","Japanese Equity","Commodities","Diversified Hedge Funds","World Government Bonds hedged","TIPS","US Aggregate Bonds","US High Yield Bonds","US Inv Grade Corporate Bonds"]}
```

I then parse this using the following code:

```
var fact = JSON.parse(fact)
```

I then wanted to write each string in one particular cell of a google sheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheer()
var col = JSON.stringify(fact.columns).split(",")
sheet.getRange(8, 2, col.length, col[0].length).setValues(col);
```

however, this doesn't work. I get a very strange sized array.It is sized 34x21 where I would have expected it to be a 1x21.

Comment: `Range#setValues` takes as input a 2d array.

Comment: @tehhowch that's why I tried the second version `JSON.stringify(fact.columns).split(",")`. However I get a weird sized array, 34x21 where I would have expected to get a 1x21.

Comment: What dimension array do you get when you access `fact.columns` without stringfying it!

Comment: Will you delete this question too? `var col = [JSON.parse(fact).columns]`

Comment: @themaster shouldn't that be `var rowData` or `var colHeaderRow`? To be a column vector spanning multiple rows OP will need to `map` each entry in `fact.columns` to it own array.

Comment: @tehhowch I maintained the name only for the next line, which checks `col` length and `setValues(col)`. Furthermore, OP states `1 row x 21 columns` (or that's how I interpreted it). I don't think there's anything in the question to suggest that the data spans multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

Firstly the API you refer to, will return a JSON String, which needs to call `JSON.Parse()` to turn it into a JavaScript object so you can access its contents. But the `fact` variable definition is creating a JavaScript object, so passing an object to `JSON.parse()` which turns JSON Strings into JavaScript objects makes no sense.

So that allows a bunch of code to be cut out.

The second major issue is that the `setValues()` call requires an array. But `fact_object.columns` needs `[]` array notation.

And finally: `fact.columns[0]` is just the length of the first string in the array. See the solution for how to use the 4 argument `getRange()`.

```
function write_json() {

  var fact_object={"columns":["Emerging Markets Sovereing Debt","Emerging Markets Corporate Bonds","US REITs","US Leveraged Loans","AC World Equity","Private Equity","US Long Treasuries","US Large Cap","US Cash","Euro area Large Cap","Emerging Markets Equity","UK Large Cap","Emerging Markets Local Currency Debt","Japanese Equity","Commodities","Diversified Hedge Funds","World Government Bonds hedged","TIPS","US Aggregate Bonds","US High Yield Bonds","US Inv Grade Corporate Bonds"]}
  Logger.log("fact_object is of type: %s",typeof(fact_object));

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  sheet.getRange(8, 2, 1, fact_object.columns.length).setValues([fact_object.columns]);

  return;
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. You are absolutely right with your first point. In the code it is a response object. I just declared it here on SO to make sure people understand that the json object is called fact.